# RestSharp DeserializeAs attribute does not seem to work for XML, only JSON

Tags: deserialization, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp.Net4 version 104.4.0.0 and am trying to use the DeserializeAs attribute as described here: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

(The returned REST result contains an XML Element with a '.' in the name, and so I can't just name my class property with the same name.)

After stepping through the RestSharp code, when using XML it appears that it never even attempts to match the name specified in the DeserializeAs attribute. However if I switch the format to JSON, then it does match against the attribute.

Can anyone confirm if the DeserializeAs attribute actually works in RestSharp.Net4 if the format is XML and not JSON?

I also found this old post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restsharp/8V9ByRYj7Xk
and am wondering if this DeserializeAs attribute is even fully implemented yet?

For now I've resorted to modifying the RestSharp code to also try removing periods from the names in addition to the default underscores and dashes.